# Xen HVM guest has severe clock drift

Tags: xen, ntp, domu, virtualization

I am seeing a very severe clock drift on my Xen HVM VPS, rented from a hosting provider, so I don't have access to the dom0 system. I continuously run ntpd, but the clock drifts by as much as 30 seconds in 5 minutes and NTP cannot keep up. Has anyone experienced this?

Here are some details:

```
$ dmesg | grep clock
[    0.160000] Measured 347 cycles TSC warp between CPUs, turning off TSC clock.
[    0.396000] * this clock source is slow. Consider trying other clock sources
[    0.550448] Switching to clocksource acpi_pm
[    0.653135] rtc_cmos 00:05: setting system clock to 2011-03-09
02:45:40 UTC (1299638740)

$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource 
acpi_pm

$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource 
acpi_pm
```

Comment: You could use the `tinker panic 0`, and `tinker step` options in your ntp.conf.  This will allow it to make corrections faster.  Not sure what you need to do to fix the real problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the beginning of ntpd.conf:

```
tinker panic 0
```

That will help it keep up.
[Here](http://lnk.nu/kb.vmware.com/q8h.do) is a link to the vmware best practices for timekeeping.  I know you're not using vmware, but much of it should still be applicable.

Comment: For whatever reason that doesn't work:
Restarting openntpd: /etc/openntpd/ntpd.conf:16: syntax error
Which is the line on which I added tinker panic 0. I am using openntpd 3.9p1+debian-5 on Ubuntu 10.10 2.6.35-22-generic-pae i686.

Comment: I missed the part about openntpd.  Losing ticks is common (and nearly unavoidable) in a virtual world.  You're going to need to get ntp to keep up somehow.  Can you run "regular" ntpd on the box?

Comment: Yes, I installed ntp instead of openntpd and added the "tinker panic 0" line to the config file; then restarted ntpd. So far the time has not changed.

Comment: By "not changed" do you mean in the good way or the bad way?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean in a bad way: as in the time is still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I recall that being an issue in guests some time back, but I couldn't recall how to get around it or fix it.  So I googled and got this solution.

Uninstall openntpd

Then create a cron job with the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash
# This is a DIRTY hack to allow have time settings correctly on Xen guests
# clopez@igalia.com
echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock
ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org 0.debian.pool.ntp.org hora.roa.es
echo 0 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock
```

This is based on the advice from this link:
http://blog.neutrino.es/2010/workaround-for-the-time-drift-issue-on-xen-keep-your-guests-synced/

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have since left the VPS provider that had this issue so I cannot say whether this works or not, but it sounds plausible. I cannot accept an answer as I cannot verify, but have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

On XEN 4.4.x server host, you can set the property tsc_mode="native" for your vm guest in file /etc/xen/vm.conf. Then, you can startup your vm and inside your vm os make a cronjob to perform a periodically synchronize time from an external ntp server.

This worked for me.